# How to implement ctrl-c handling in a rust web server

Tags: multithreading, rust, tcp, channel

This is a question about the web server example provided in the Rust Lang Book

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-03-graceful-shutdown-and-cleanup.html

Just implemented the graceful shutdown traits but I want to add support for `ctrl-c`, the official example uses `.take(2)` which is quite useless in the real world.

I came across the crate [ctrlc](https://detegr.github.io/doc/ctrlc/) but I'm not sure how to solve this problem because the web server is waiting on incoming TCP connections, even If I spawn a thread to receive the `ctrl-c` signal I don't know how to interrupt `listener.incoming()` bit.

```
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    let stream = stream.unwrap();

    pool.execute(|| {
        handle_connection(stream);
    });
}
```

My best guess would be to spawn the `listener.incoming()` bit into a thread that writes to a channel some type that would wrap `Result<TcpStream>` and `Result<GotShutdownOrder>`.

Any input on how to best solve this would be much appreciated